# Couchdb-lucene for couchdb with admins and members

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-lucene

I'm trying to use couchdb-lucene with couchdb and I keep getting {"code": 500} errors.

I have a couchdb that has an Admin and Member set. The authentication with couchdb is done via Cookie authentication. When I try and use couchdb-lucene, e.g. via

```
http://localhost:5984/_fti/local/databasename/_design/quicksearch/by_phrase?q=test
```

I keep getting the 500 error. The corresponding couchdb-lucene log entry is

Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}

When I try and connect to couchdb-lucene, the auth cookie is added to the request, so it should be passed to couchdb? If I remove the Admin and Members from the database, all works fine.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. I don't use require_auth_user with couchdb and thus did not add a user and password in the couchdb-lucene config file.

Thanks,

Kiran

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. The code for cookie pass through was actually added to couchdb-lucene, but for some reason my git repo didn't have that version. See https://github.com/kika/couchdb-lucene/commit/435ee2f325e9d7c7b3120168694f3eaca3483737